# JS callback function issue?

Tags: javascript, arrays, foreach, callback

I'm attempting to create a function which accepts an array and a callback function. The function should return true if all values in the array passed to the callback return true, otherwise, return false. But I'm not sure what I'm doing incorrectly

```
const every = function(arr, callback) {
   arr.forEach(function(element) {     
     if(!callback(element)) {       
       return false         
     }       
   })      
   return true  
};  

every([1, 2, 3, 4, 5], function(val) {
    return val < 2
});
```

expected results => false
but I'm getting true.

Comment: A return inside the callback to the forEach method does *absolutely nothing* in the function in which that method was called. I'd suggest filtering the array and testing the resulting length. Alternatively, newer versions of JavaScript actually have an every method on arrays: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/every

Comment: Is it just me or is the callback being passed in malformed syntatically?  The `{}` at the end of it looks strange

Comment: `Array.prototype` has an `every` that does what you want, e.g. `[1, 2, 3, 4, 5].every(val => val < 2)`

Comment: @ic3b3rg He's obviously trying to understand how to implement a similar function himself.

Comment: @Barmar Not so sure he's aware of `Array.prototype.every`

Comment: I'm guessing it's an academic exercise, so that's irrelevant.

Answer (score 1):

Returning `false` from the `forEach` callback will not also cause the `every` function to return. Instead it will simply continue the `forEach` iterator.

The most easy solution to your problem would be a [`for...of`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/for...of) loop, since it allows you to use a `return` pattern similar to your snippet:

```js
const every = function(arr, callback) {

  for (const element of arr) {
    if (!callback(element)) {
      return false;
    }
  }

  return true;
};

console.log(every([1, 2, 3, 4, 5], function(val) {
  return val < 2;
}));
```

**Note:** By using a loop construct `every` *returns early*. The `forEach` method of arrays always runs until all array elements are visited, but the loop breaks immediately after one element fails the test. A regular `for` loop would give you the same performance benefit.

Comment: This is good to know. I was wondering why the loop continues to iterate even after the condition was met. Thanks for this!

Answer (score 1):

I would recommend using a simple for loop:

```
    const every = (arr, callback) => {
       for (let i = 0; i < arr.length; i++){
          if (callback(arr[i]) === false){
             return false;
       }
    }
       return true;
    };  

    console.log(every([1, 2, 3, 4, 5], function(val){return val < 2}));
```

Answer (score 0):

You could potentially use reduce() for this.  If you base your reduction on the truth and the result of the callback, it will remain true so long as the callback is true.  Once a callback is false, the check for `truth` in the conditional will short circuit the logic and the callback will not execute anymore.  It will loop through all the elements though.

It also returns true for an empty array, which seems to match your original logics intent.

```js
const every = function(arr, callback) {
  return arr.reduce(function(truth, element){
    return truth && callback(element);
  }, true);
};  

console.log(
  every([1, 2, 3, 4, 5], function(val){return val < 2})
);

console.log(
  every([], function(val){return val < 2})
);
```

Comment: Though as @ic3b3rg pointed out, Array.prototype.every exists, and appears to have close to the same browser support as Array.prototype.reduce

Answer (score 0):

```
arr.forEach(function(element) {
    return false
})
```

Its the inner function returning false, which have no effect for the outer function (in this situation)
you should create a new variable inside the outer function and instead of returning false in the inner function, change the variable
at the end just return the variable

```
const every = function(arr, callback) {
    let isEvery = true
    arr.forEach(function(element) {     
        if(!callback(element)) { // or just isEvery = isEvery && statement
            isEvery = false
         }       
     })      
    return isEvery
};
```